# Designing API for length constrained input array

Tags: api-design

I need to expose an API A which internally uses another API B. API B accepts an array of product codes and returns their information. That array could have any length but API B will return information of only first 10 product codes and silently discard the rest, i.e. doesn't throw an exception or return an error.

Now while designing API A, how should I go about it? Should I also discard the extra elements silently or throw an exception or return partial information with an error?

I can also split the input in batches and call API B multiple times from API A but each call to API B has to wait for 1 second.

Comment: What do the clients of API A want?  Correct but slow behavior, silent wrong behavior, or an error suggesting they try a smaller query?  And maybe there's other choices, if implementation A caches some of API B's results.

Comment: I wish my customers thought defective code was good. I'd be thought a genius and get a pay raise.